# PowerShell custom output @{n=;e=}

Tags: powershell

I'm not very clear on how the @{n=;e=} construct works in PowerShell.
Does this type of thing have a name that I can find examples from?

For example, I find examples like this that works great:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, VolumeName, @{n="Size(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="Free(GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

When I try to do something like that, I can never get it to work. This works fine:

```
Get-Command -Module Microsoft.Powershell.Utility | Where CommandType -eq Function | Select Name,Version,CommandType
```

So I thought I would try and add the definition of that function to a new column using `cat function:\$_.Name`

```
Get-Command -Module Microsoft.Powershell.Utility | Where CommandType -eq Function | Select Name,Version,CommandType,@{n="Contents"; e={cat function:\$_.Name}}
```

But I just get an empty `Contents` column :(
Can someone give me some pointers on how the @{n=;e=} construct works?
Also, what do the `n` and `e` stand for?

Comment: Yours is a string parsing issue, please see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing). `cat function:\$_.Name` -> `cat function:\$($_.Name)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@{n='';e={}}` syntax is called a calculated property. n stands for Name and e stands for expression. You can even specify Name instead of n and Expression instead of e.

Calculated properties allow you to create new properties or change existing ones. This is done by passing a special hashtable to the Property parameter rather than a static property name. This is a useful feature where you create new properties using custom expression in a script block and use existing properties.

Not for only Select-Object this work for also Format-Table, Format-List cmdlets. These don't work outside this cmdlets.

Calculated properties are a quick way to manipulate command output to return just about anything you like. These save your time and reduce code length.

Sidenote: The last code in your question dosent work because you need to join two path using Join-Path. Calculated properties are innocent here. Even you can join path like this: `cat "Function:\$($_.Name)"` as @MathiasR.Jessen pointed.

Answer (score 1):

`@{}` is a hashtable.  `{}` is a scriptblock inside the hashtable set equal to e.  The hashtable is used in a custom way for select-object.

```
$scriptblock = { $_ } 
$hashtable = @{ name = 'number'
          expression = $scriptblock
              }

1..3 | select-object -property $hashtable


number
------
     1
     2
     3
```